# SharePoint 2013 GEO-Replications?

Tags: 2013, performance, replication, geolocation

We have a SharePoint 2013 environment that is running quite well in Europe, However, Our end-users in other offices in North America are not satisfied with the performance, Because they are experiencing unacceptable delay in very simple activities such as: Viewing/Editing/Uploading documents.

What would you do in such situation? How to improve the user experience of the SharePoint users that are distributes in different far geographical locations?

We thought about creating another SharePoint 2013 environment in North America and replicate/Sync Up data between the two farms.... How does that sound?

We heard for commercial solutions from AvePoint and Metalogix - Any experiences to share, Please?

PS: I must mention that Office 365 & SharePoint Online are totally out of the question, and we don't want them at all.

Comment: Office 365 does not support your scenario any way. Your tenant would be bound to a specific data center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I read it, the first idea that came to mind was syncing/mirroring across the two farms. Another idea is to have multiple farms, one in North America that those end-users use, and another separate farm in Europe that Europeans use. These farm can connect and sync up with one another with Search, MMS, User Profile Service, BCS, etc. There is no need for North America users to have to collaborate between each other using European servers. There should be a North American hub farm. So in retrospect:

- Have your existing farm replicated to another farm in North America using 3rd party tools. I know AvePoint has High Availablity and Metalogix has Replicator. Both are very respectable companies so you should be in good hands with either.
- Create a North American farm to allow collaboration nationally.

Comment: You can also have half your farm in the US, other half in Europe, then use your load balancer (F5 or whatever) to send people to the preferred ones based on subnet. At that point, the only slowness would be between the US & Europe servers - users would go to a quick WFE server though.